# Looping from an array, if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, for-loop

I've been wondering if this is the correct way for me to loop from an array, before I continue writing my code. My main concerns are with the link *(var link = ... )* and the *if* statement.

Is this the correct way to run through array1, and see if the value returned is less than/equal to the corresponding value in array2? Is there a more efficient way, if my code is correct (which I doubt, but I am currently unable to test it).

Also, would this loop through every element of array1 indefinitely, or just one of them indefinitely?

```
var array1 = [741, 451, 54188, 5847, 5418, 54944, 310, 541, 7451, 10211, 113, 9115, 62, 2841, 52482481, 24];
var array2 = [15, 418, 488, 130000, 8482, 55, 16, 14, 2546, 651, 4521, 11, 54, 659, 542, 1152];

var myObj = {};
array1.forEach(function(item, i) {
    myObj[item] = array2[i];
});

var Loop = setInterval(function(){ 
    for (var prop in array1) {
        var link = "http://blahblahblah.com/blah/" + array1[prop] + "/blahblah"
        $.get(link,function(data){
            var dataGiven = $("span.cost-in-usd:first-child").text();
            dataGiven = Number(dataGiven.replace(",",""));
            dataGiven = Number(dataGiven.replace("(",""));
            dataGiven = Number(dataGiven.replace(")",""));
            if (dataGiven <= myObj[prop]) {
                //stuff happens
            }
        });
    }
},0)
```

Comment: `prop`'s gonna change. also ajax in a loop in a `setInterval(..., 0)` whoa

Comment: You really should be casting to a number once. I don't know of any numbers that have brackets in them.

Comment: Note that jQuery has an `each()` method that normalizes everything and can be used with both objects and arrays.

Comment: Anything with **(, )** casted to Number will produce **NaN**, `isNaN(Number('(100)'))` – how yours replace works?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski So, I should just get rid of Number(), and use dataGiven.replace()?

Comment: @adeneo Would you be willing to explain how I could use this in my code? jQuery isn't my strong point, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sure, something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/EC8g7/1/**

Comment: @adeneo That doesn't seem to work when I change the bits of the URL to the one I'm using (which I won't release), and when I add a simple console.log to the if statement, then put an else after that with a console.log inside. Is it taking dataGiven?

Comment: I can't really test it properly, but the testing I have done shows it  working perfectly fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/EC8g7/3/**

Answer (score 0):

The `for in` statement is used to loop through properties of an object. While it will work with an array sometimes, here's a more proper way to do it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var value = array[i];
    //Do stuff
}
```

For the second part of your question, I believe that would loop indefinitely. You do not need to set an interval to loop through an array. What that will do is loop through the array entirely every 0 milliseconds.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `Array.forEach()`, it's the `for in` command that can have issues.

Comment: Right, which is why I wonder what the use of expanding to the long-form `for` is all about.

Comment: Habit and convention also, this is how arrays have been iterated over in nearly every language. `Array.forEach()` is a different way to do it, it comes down to preference

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it if I were you :

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] <= array2[i]) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

`forEach` works just as well.

For your concerns with `var link = ...` so long as it is a valid path and you don't forget to put the `;` at the end you are good.

Comment: How would that work? I want to see if the value for each of the elements of array1 (given by the link, the variable for which is _dataGiven_) is less than/equal to the corresponding value for the element of array1, which is shown in array2.

Comment: For example, myObj[741] (the first element in array1) is 15 (the first element in array2). So... _dataGiven_ is the value of array1, found on a website that I know of. I want to see if _dataGiven_ is less than/equal to the corresponding value of each element in array1, which is seen in array2.

Comment: So... If the value given by 741 on the site is less than the corresponding value seen in array2 (which is why _myObj_ exists), it'll return something like "Selling for cheap!". At least, that's what I'm trying to do, in the end.

Comment: @user3810560 kind of confused as to what you are trying to do with `dataGiven` and the array's. You have them hard-coded in, what is the format of the data you are retrieving with `$.get`? and you should brush up on your arrays, because `myObj[741]` will not give you the first element in the array, rather the 742nd element in the array (if it exists). The first element is retrieved by `myObj[0]` so `array1[0] = 741` and `array2[0] = 15`

Comment: Take a look at this (just the first two blocks of code, with `alert(myObj[741])` added on to the end. http://jsfiddle.net/SU88L/

Comment: So now what exactly is your question?